# How do I require an input in a textbox if a certain checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
 <form>
        <label>Skills</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
        <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skill2" value="Python">
        <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skill3" value="C#">
        <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skill4" value="C#">
        <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skill5" value="C#">
        <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skill6" value="C#">
        <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skill7" value="C#">
        <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skill8" value="C#">
        <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skill9" value="C#">
        <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skill10" value="C#">
        <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="other" value="other">
        <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <textarea id="otherbox" name="subject" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Apply">
      </form>
```

How do I make it so that, if the "other" checkbox is selected, the textbox must be filled out or the form cannot be submitted. I must use JavaScript to do this. Please explain in detail because I'm rather new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily achieve this using JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="other"
    name="other"
    value="other"
    onclick="otherCheckBox()"
  />
```

(Just add an **onclick** event to your *'other'* checkbox, so that it fires off a function whenever clicked)

JS:

```
<script>
  function otherCheckBox() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("other");  //Getting the 'other' CheckBox
    var otherBox = document.getElementById("otherbox");  //Getting the TextBox
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      otherBox.required = "true"; //Setting the 'required' parameter to true if checkbox is checked
    } else {
      otherBox.required = "";  //Setting the 'required' parameter to false if the checkbox is not checked
    }
  }
</script>
```

Add this Script tag in your *html head*.

When fired, This function will check if the checkbox with id ***other*** is checked. If it is checked, it will set the ***required*** attribute of the textbox with id ***otherbox*** to true, and if not checked, it will set it to false.